Error: Value of type 'FetchedResults<Item>.Element' (aka 'Item') has no member 'price2pay'
I am trying to loop through my Core Data Database to get all the prices of all the Items but I'm getting the error, Value of type 'FetchedResults.Element' (aka 'Item') has no member 'price2pay' below is my CartView.swift. Would someone please assist me on how to fix this?
//
//  CartView.swift
//  PonnasKitchen
//
//  Created by Sricharan Ponna on 02/08/2024.
//  Copyright © 2024 Sricharan Ponna. All rights reserved.
//

import SwiftUI

func forLoop() {
    @FetchRequest(sortDescriptors: []) var checkout: FetchedResults<Item>
    @Environment(\.managedObjectContext) var moc
    var subTotal: Int32 = 0
    do {
        for i in checkout {
            subTotal = try! i.price2pay + subTotal // Error is here
        }
    }
}

struct CartView: View {
    
    @FetchRequest(sortDescriptors: []) var checkout: FetchedResults<Item>
    @Environment(\.managedObjectContext) var moc
    
    @State var subTotal: Int32 = 0
    @State var productPrices: [Int32] = []
    
    
    
    var body: some View {
        
        NavigationStack {
            List {
                ForEach(checkout) { product in
                    VStack(alignment: .leading, spacing: 8) {
                        
                        Text((product.name ?? "Chicken Biryani"))
                            .font(.system(size: 20, design: .rounded).bold())
                        
                        Text("Quantity: \(product.qty)")
                            .font(.callout.bold())
                        
                        Text("Price of Each: £\(Int32(product.price))")
                            .font(.callout.bold())
                        
                        Text("Price to pay: £\(product.price2Pay)")
                            .font(.callout.bold())
                    }
                    .swipeActions {
                        Button(role: .destructive) {
                            do {
                                let item2Delete = try moc.existingObject(with: product.objectID)
                                moc.delete(item2Delete)
                                Task(priority: .background) {
                                    try await moc.perform {
                                        try moc.save()
                                    }
                                }
                            } catch {
                                print(error)
                            }
                        } label: {
                            Label("Delete", systemImage: "trash.fill")
                        }
                        
                    }
                    .frame(maxWidth: .infinity, alignment: .leading)
                }
            }
            HStack() {
                Text("Subtotal: ")
                    .padding(.horizontal)
                Spacer()
                Text("£\(subTotal).00")
                    .padding(.horizontal)
                Spacer()
                NavigationLink(destination: PurchaseView()) {
                    HStack {
                        Image(systemName: "creditcard.and.123")
                            .symbolVariant(.fill)
                        Divider()
                            .padding(.vertical, 8)
                        Text("Proceed to Buy")
                    }
                    .frame(minWidth: 150, maxHeight: 55)
                    .background(.mint)
                    .foregroundColor(.white)
                    .clipShape(RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 8))
                }
            }
        }
        .navigationTitle("Checkout")
    }
}

struct ItemCardView: View {
    
    
    var body: some View {
        HStack {
            Text("card")
                .font(.system(size: 25))
        }
    }
}

//struct CartTitleView: View {
//    
//    var body: some View {
//        VStack(content: {
//            Text("Cart")
//                .font(.title2)
//                .fontWeight(.heavy)
//        })
//    }
//}

#Preview {
    CartView()
}


I am trying to loop through my Core Data Database to get all the prices of all the Items but I'm getting the error, Value of type 'FetchedResults.Element' (aka 'Item') has no member 'price2pay' below is my CartView.swift. Would someone please assist me on how to fix this?
Below is my core datamodel
CoreDataModel

Can you show the code for Item. Why do you have a try! i.price2pay + subTotal instead of just i.price2pay + subTotal?
It is not clear from your code where you declare and call forLoop() and why you have this function outside of any View, as it should be inside a View.

SwiftUI wrappers only work at a View/struct level

Remove the very strange forLoop function and change subTotal to be a computed property instead.
var subTotal: Int32 {
    var result: Int32 = .zero
    for i in checkout {
        result =  i.price2pay + subTotal // Error is here
    }
    return result
}

or shorter
var subTotal: Int32 {
    checkout.reduce(into: Int32.zero) { $0 += $1.price2pay }
}

